# Closing a FileInputStream used by struts' stream result

Tags: java, struts2, download, struts, fileinputstream

My web application generates an XML file. I'm using a Struts2 stream result to manage the download, here's the action in struts.xml:

```
<action name="generateXML" class="navigation.actions.GenerateXML">
    <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/xml</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
    ...
</action>
```

Here's the part of the action class "GenerateXML" where the FileInputStream "inputStream" is created:

```
public String execute() {
    File xml = new File(filename);
    ...//fill the file with stuff
    try {
        setInputStream(new FileInputStream(xml));
    } finally {
        //inputStream.close();
        xml.delete();
    }
}
```

Deleting the file won't work because the inputStream isn't closed yet (That part is commented out). However, if i close it at this point the xml file downloaded by the user is empty since its stream was closed before struts generates the download.
Besides using a script that regularly deletes those temporary files on the server, is there a way to close "inputStream" AFTER struts has done its thing?

Comment: Matthew's reference is pretty good. Another option would be to do the file cleanup in an interceptor after `invoke()`. That's potentially more customizeable, though it may not matter in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a delete on close input stream, but you can write your own. See [is there an existing FileInputStream delete on close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693968/is-there-an-existing-fileinputstream-delete-on-close).

The idea is that you don't pass a FileInputStream, but pass your ClosingFileInputStream, which overrides close and deletes the file when close is called. The close() will be called by struts:

```
public String execute() {    
    File xml = new File(filename);
        ...//fill the file with stuff
        setInputStream(new ClosingFileInputStream(xml));   
    }
```

See the linked question for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You need not do that.
Struts2 will take care to close the steam itself all you need to do is to create a input stream and set it.

Here is how struts2 handle stream closing for you

```
public class StreamResult extends StrutsResultSupport {
  // removing all other code
      {
        // Flush
                oOutput.flush();
                }
                   finally {
                if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                  if (oOutput != null) oOutput.close();
               }

    }
```

So since stream is a result type in struts2 what it doing is that it picking the data from the stream you have defined flushing it and den closing it.

i hope it will clear your doubt.

Comment: The thing is, after Struts is done I don't have control over the file which used that stream anymore, so I can't delete it. Matthew's solution worked.